# Astropy get_gcrs_posvel in Python 2.7

Tags: python, astropy

In Python 2.7 I am trying to calculate the position and velocity of an observatory by doing

```
>>> from astropy.time import Time
>>> from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord, EarthLocation, ICRS
>>> from astropy import units as u
>>> from astropy import coordinates
>>> time=Time(58121.93, format='mjd')
>>> location=EarthLocation(53.2367, 2.3085, 100, ellipsoid = None)
>>> op, ov = location.get_gcrs_posvel(time)
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\earth.py", line 653, in get_gcrs_posvel
    gcrs_data = self._get_gcrs(obstime).data
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\earth.py", line 633, in _get_gcrs
    return itrs.transform_to(GCRS(obstime=obstime))
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\baseframe.py", line 934, in transform_to
    return trans(self, new_frame)
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\transformations.py", line 1314, in __call__
    curr_coord = t(curr_coord, curr_toframe)
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\transformations.py", line 847, in __call__
    reprwithoutdiff = supcall(from_diffless, toframe)
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\builtin_frames\intermediate_rotation_transforms.py", line 72, in cirs_to_gcrs
    return gcrs.transform_to(gcrs_frame)
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\baseframe.py", line 934, in transform_to
    return trans(self, new_frame)
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\transformations.py", line 1314, in __call__
    curr_coord = t(curr_coord, curr_toframe)
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\transformations.py", line 914, in __call__
    return supcall(fromcoord, toframe)
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\builtin_frames\icrs_cirs_transforms.py", line 221, in gcrs_to_gcrs
    return from_coo.transform_to(ICRS).transform_to(to_frame)
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\baseframe.py", line 934, in transform_to
    return trans(self, new_frame)
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\transformations.py", line 1314, in __call__
    curr_coord = t(curr_coord, curr_toframe)
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\transformations.py", line 914, in __call__
    return supcall(fromcoord, toframe)
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\builtin_frames\icrs_cirs_transforms.py", line 188, in gcrs_to_icrs
    i_ra, i_dec = aticq(gcrs_ra, gcrs_dec, astrom)
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\builtin_frames\utils.py", line 196, in aticq
    before = norm(ppr-d)
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\builtin_frames\utils.py", line 125, in norm
    return p/np.sqrt(np.einsum('...i,...i', p, p))[..., np.newaxis]
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\einsumfunc.py", line 1087, in einsum
    einsum_call=True)
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\einsumfunc.py", line 688, in einsum_path
    input_subscripts, output_subscript, operands = _parse_einsum_input(operands)
  File "C:\p\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\einsumfunc.py", line 432, in _parse_einsum_input
    raise TypeError("For this input type lists must contain "
TypeError: For this input type lists must contain either int or Ellipsis
```

Comment: I get `op,ov = (<CartesianRepresentation (x, y, z) in m
     (-4205308.60307185,  4788305.10424286,  262644.44317487)>,
 <CartesianRepresentation (x, y, z) in m / s
     (-349.16875571, -306.65597541,  0.)>)` with Python 3.6. Googling "For this input type lists must contain either int or Ellipsis" leads me to [this thread](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/7051) where it looks (from a quick glance) like it has to do with the numpy/astropy version. I suggest an upgrade, and if it doesn't help, it's probably more a question for StackOverflow. I don't think it has to do with astronomy.

Comment: I forgot to say I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Well, if upgrading doesn't work, try asking the question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as per pela's comment

Answer (score 0):

I searched for this issue on Astropy's issue tracker and came across this:

[numpy TypeError on coordinate transform (TypeError: For this input type lists must contain either int or Ellipsis)](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/7051)

It was fixed as of Astropy v2.0.4, so, pretty recent.  You should be able to upgrade your Astropy.